# Tangency portfolio with two additional constraints so that portfolio weights are unconstrained

Tags: portfolio-optimization, optimization, mean-variance, markowitz

I know that the formula for determining the weights of the Tangency portfolio is given as  $w_{tan}$ = $\frac{\Sigma \mu}{\iota^{\prime}\Sigma\mu }$, but I was wondering how to derive the weights in case we add the constraints that the weights should be larger than or equal to -1, and smaller than or equal to 1.

I was wondering whether there is a closed form solution available, and/or what the derivation looks like?

I guess the optimisation problem would look something like this:
$$ \frac{w^{\prime}\mu}{\sqrt{w^{\prime}\Sigma w}}
$$
s.t. 
$$ w^{\prime}\iota = 1
$$
$$ w_{i} \geq -1,  \forall i = 1, \dots, N
$$
$$ w_{i} \leq 1,  \forall i = 1, \dots, N
$$

Please correct me if this is the wrong representation of the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there are two ways to solve the tangency portfolio:

- closed-form analytical solution
- optimization problem (maximization of the Sharpe ratio)

The **closed-form analytical solution** you incorrectly wrote is actually

$$w_{\text{tan}} = \frac{\Sigma^{-1} \left(\mu - r_f \cdot \iota\right)}{\iota^{\prime}\Sigma^{-1}\left(\mu - r_f \cdot \iota\right)}$$

This *is already* the **unconstrained maximum Sharpe ratio portfolio**, where "unconstrained" means short-selling is allowed so that weights can be larger than or equal to $-1$ (in other words, less than $0$), and smaller than or equal to $1$. For the equivalent **optimization problem** we therefore don't need to impose additional constraints (besides the sum-to-1 rule) in order to "unconstrain" the weights since the unconstrained portfolio is an unconstrained problem.

On the other hand, the **constrained max Sharpe portfolio**, where short-sales are forbidden, does *not* have a simple closed-form analytical solution like the unconstrained portfolio, and *does* require an additional constraint of non-negativity, $w_i \geq 0 \enspace \forall i=1,\dots,N$.